# Using the html <progress> tag with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created an html progress tag that I want updated every time a button is clicked up to a maximum of 5 times. I've sorted out the code to update the progress tag courtesy of another source, but as I am a JS novice I can't figure out how to link the button in. 
Any help would be appreciated.
Here is my javascript.

```
$(document).ready( function (){ 

$("#submit").click( function(){

$("#pro-form input").on("click",function(){   

var numValid = 0;
$("#pro-form input[required]").each(function() {
if (this.validity.valid) {
    numValid++;
}
});

var progress = $("#progress"),
progressMessage = $("#progress-message");

if (numValid == 0) {
progress.attr("value", "0");
progressMessage.text("The form, it wants you.");
}
if (numValid == 1) {
progress.attr("value", "20");
progressMessage.text("There you go, great start!");
}
if (numValid == 2) {
progress.attr("value", "40");
progressMessage.text("Nothing can stop you now.");
}
if (numValid == 3) {
progress.attr("value", "60");
progressMessage.text("You're basically a hero, right?");
}
if (numValid == 4) {
progress.attr("value", "80");
progressMessage.text("They are going to write songs about you.");
}
if (numValid == 5) {
progress.attr("value", "95");
progressMessage.text("SO CLOSE. PRESS THE THING.");
}

    });
});
});
```

css

```
  *{
      box-sizing:border-box;}   

  body{
   /* background:#333; */
      background-image:url(../images/progress_grunge_background.gif);
      font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Tahoma, Sans-Serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 1.4;
      padding: 20px;}

  #accessbox {
      background-color:#006;
      width:200px;
      height: 100px;
      position:fixed;
      -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
      -moz-border-radius: 1px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 2px solid red;
      left:190px;
      top: 400px; }

  form {
      padding-top:10px;
      padding-left:25px;
      position:relative;}

  input[type="text"], [type="password"], [type="submit"] {
      font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
      background-color:#99FFFF;
      margin:2px;
      border:2px solid #999;}

  input[type="submit"] {
      margin-top:5px;
      margin-left:20px; }   

  progress {
      width:200px;
      height:20px;}

  .progress-wrap {
      top:550px;
      left:210px;
      position:relative;
     /* text-align: center; */
      font-size: 10px;
      color: red;
      margin: 0 0 20px 0;
      progress {
      width: 100%; 
      margin: 0 0 5px 0; 
    }
  }
```

html

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title>Untitled Document</title>
      <link href="css/access.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <script src="_js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>                                       
      <script src="_js/modernizr.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

  <div class = "accessbox" id="accessbox">

          <form method="post" class="login" action="">

          <input type="text" class="name" id="username" placeholder="Username"  name="username" />

          <input type="password" class="pass" placeholder="Password"  name="password"/>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" id="submit">
      <script src="js/progress_1.js"></script>
          </form>   
  </div>        
  <div class="progress-wrap">
            <progress max="100" value="0" id="progress"></progress>
            <div class="progress-message" id="progress-message">The form, it wants you.</div>
            <!--script src="js/progress.js"></script-->

  </div>       


  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: would you mind to add this in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) as a demo.

Answer (score 0):

you just need little reorder

here you go..

```
var numValid = 0;

$(document).ready( function (){ 

$("#pro-form input").on("click",function(){   
$("#pro-form input[required]").each(function() {
if (this.validity.valid) {
    numValid++;
}
   });
  });

$("#submit").click( function(){

var progress = $("#progress"),
progressMessage = $("#progress-message");

if (numValid == 0) {
progress.attr("value", "0");
progressMessage.text("The form, it wants you.");
}
if (numValid == 1) {
progress.attr("value", "20");
progressMessage.text("There you go, great start!");
}
if (numValid == 2) {
progress.attr("value", "40");
progressMessage.text("Nothing can stop you now.");
}
if (numValid == 3) {
progress.attr("value", "60");
progressMessage.text("You're basically a hero, right?");
}
if (numValid == 4) {
progress.attr("value", "80");
progressMessage.text("They are going to write songs about you.");
}
if (numValid == 5) {
progress.attr("value", "95");
progressMessage.text("SO CLOSE. PRESS THE THING.");
}


});
});
```

Comment: Many thanks. I've tried your solution but it's still not working for me. However, I wonder if the problem lies in the "link up" between the javascript and the html/css. I've taken the liberty of posting both below. The only change I've made in the javascript is #pro-form input is now #input.

Comment: Just discovered that the code is too big to post in a comment box so I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: I've added that code to the original javascript. What I'm trying to do is create a login page with a progress tag that advances each time a incorrect login is entered. This code is just a demo. Sorry for all the comments. Ignorance of this site!